# Formula problem with Multiple Condition

Tags: formula, if

I need help please,

I created two fields, the first is "Group" of text type and the second is "status" of formula type

The status must check the condition of If Group contains '9','MIN','TER', 'CLO', 'closed', then the "status" field is inactive else active

Taking into consideration that this update should not impact all accounts. Only for users of the "App" application who have profiles starting with "App"

==>  the formula :

```
IF( BEGINS( $Profile.Name, "App" ),
  Group__c = "9" , "MIN" ,"TER" , "CLO" , "closed" ,"inactif", "actif")
```

my question is how to correct my formula so that it respects the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AND() condition and OR() condition to verify in If and based on the output you should assign the Active or Inactive. Can you try using the below formula.

```
IF(AND( BEGINS( $Profile.Name, 'App' ),OR(Group__c = '9' ,Group__c='MIN',Group__c='TER',Group__c='CLO', Group__c='Closed')
),'inactive','Active')
```

Go through the [Trialhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) for more details on the Salesforce Formulas

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: when i used your formula , the syntax was correct , but i always have just the value Inactive even if i give to the Group another value .

Comment: Are you trying to update the group__c value other than above values?

Comment: Now when I put in group_c another value apart from what exists in the condition, the status always remains the same, normally it should change to Active but I always have Inactive

Comment: I don't see any issue with the formula in my org. Can you try removing the first profile condition and check .. `IF(AND( or(Group__c = '9' ,Group__c='MIN',Group__c='TER',Group__c='CLO', Group__c='Closed')
),'inactive','Active')`

Comment: I tried to remove the profile condition and it work , but i need also this condition .

Comment: Is your user profile starting with App?

Comment: yes it start with App